# How do I resolve a cyclic dependency in Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the crates `oauth2` (v4.1.0) and `sqlx[json]` (v0.5.5):

```
[dependencies]
oauth2 = "4.1.0"
sqlx = { version = "0.5.5", features = ["json"] }
```

When attempting to build, I am getting the following error:

```
error: cyclic package dependency: package `ahash v0.7.4` depends on itself. Cycle:
package `ahash v0.7.4`
    ... which is depended on by `hashbrown v0.11.2`
    ... which is depended on by `indexmap v1.7.0`
    ... which is depended on by `serde_json v1.0.64`
    ... which is depended on by `wasm-bindgen v0.2.74`
    ... which is depended on by `js-sys v0.3.51`
    ... which is depended on by `getrandom v0.2.3`
    ... which is depended on by `ahash v0.7.4`
```

This only happens when I activate the `json` feature flag on `sqlx`.  How do I troubleshoot this kind of problem?  Are there any workarounds to make these libs/features work together? What are the alternatives?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ``` is there any way that I can solve this ? ```

Comment: I changed the question part so you are more pleased

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem as you described so I cleaned up your question.  I do not have further feedback on why you're getting a cyclic dependency since `oauth2` doesn't seem to depend on `ahash` after looking at its lockfile.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the issue, but it is due to conflicting features activated by `oauth` and `sqlx`. Specifically `oauth` introduces a dependency `getrandom → js-sys` which is not present when `getrandom` is used by `sqlx`, while `sqlx` introduces a dependency `hashbrown → ahash` which is not present when `hashbrown` is used by `oauth`. So `oauth` and `sqlx` each work in isolation but introduce the cycle when used together.

Comment: downgrade oauth2 = "3.0.0" to solve it

Comment: I am having a similar problem of this issue, but with the direct requested dependencies of:
`sea-orm` and `openidconnect`. If I comment out either of those, cargo check works again. I tried to use `sqlx` or `sea-query` instead and both worked together with openidconnect. Using the following specs in Cargo.toml:
- `sea-orm = { version = "0.2.5", features = [ "sqlx-postgres", "runtime-tokio-native-tls", "macros" ], default-features = false }`
- `openidconnect = "2"`

I have no solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

After trying a few things back and forth, the only solution I found, was to update the lockfile to the latest version, using:

```sh
cargo update
```

After that, `cargo clean && cargo build` worked like a charm! Seems like some older patch versions seem to have conflicts, but the changes in the Cargo.lock were too big to track down, which crate combination it was. I hope that helps anybody else!

EDIT: After more communication and searching, I got referred to an issue directly at the ahash github project: https://github.com/tkaitchuck/aHash/issues/95.

According to that, the actual official "workaround" was / is, to pin the indexmap crate to:

```
indexmap = "=1.6.2"
```

However when looking into my Cargo.lock file, it seems to work with now:

```
indexmap = "1.7"
```